# dropdownlist custom databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net

DropDownList inside Gridview.

Database Schema:

```
Restaurants       Menus           Products
RestaurantID      MenuID          ProductID  
RestaurantName    MenuName        ProductName
                  RestaurantID    MenuID
```

it doesnt work with this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3"
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MenuID") %>'  DataTextField="RestaurantName" DataValueField="RestaurantID">
```

Gridview has GetAllProducts method.

ObjectDataSource3 has GetAllRestaurants method.

I want to edit and insert Menus of each Product. But I want to show RestaurantName indtead of MenuID..

When you want to bind Questions and Categories (just two) tables, this can work easily:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CategoryID") %>' DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryID">
```

I have 3 tables to reach data.. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You have edited your original question with my suggested code but it still doesnt work. You should give more feedback about exceptions or results.

Comment: @Tim Actually I mentioned above is logically wrong. I couldnt write correct binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropdownlist has a Property DataTextField for this purpose.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3"
                     SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MenuID") %>' DataTextField="RestaurantName" DataValueField="RestaurantID">
```